# Can Win10 IOT automatically connect to unsecured / open Wifi?

Tags: wifi, pi-2, windows-iot

I have an idea for a Windows 10 IOT project, and am wondering if the device will be able to be configured to automatically connect to open (not password protected) public wifi hotspots?

The usage scenario I'm looking for is a device that can have sensors and connect to the internet to report metrics gathered when any wifi network is in range. It would be nice to be able to connect to a preconfigured list of secured networks as well, but open wifi networks / hotspots is the requirement.

Does anyone know how to setup / configure / program Windows 10 for IOT on Raspberry Pi 2 to automatically connect to open wifi networks when available?

Comment: Looks like this link may help, but doesn't give the specific scenario I'm wanting to configure https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupWiFi.htm

Comment: It looks like it could be done programmatically http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/WifiConnectSample.htm